# Karate: Is there a way to disable log when using retry?

Tags: logging, karate

I'm using Karate for validation tests.

I setup a retry on one of my request but sometimes there is more than 100 retry, this create to big useless logs with the same big payload on each request...
And this bloat my CI.

I want to reduce this logs quantity, maybe by disable log for just this request ?

I've tried `* configure report = false` but this disable only on Cucumber html report.
I want to disable also in STDOUT console.

So maybe with some form of log level manipulation setted in the `logback-test.xml` ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you con't disable logs per request, you can switch off everything by setting the log level to `INFO` - but I guess you don't want that. 100 retries sounds very unusual to me. You can try your luck with a feature request - but I can tell you that this would be low priority unless someone contributes code.

If this really bothers you, write some custom Java code to do this polling + HTTP request and call it from Karate.

EDIT: I think I have a solution that will work for you. You can completely disable the Karate logs appearing on the console - while still having the HTML report with this change to the `logback-test.xml`:

```
<root level="warn">
    <!-- <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" /> -->
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
</root>
```

So just commenting out the console log appender will do the trick !

Also read: https://github.com/intuit/karate#report-verbosity

Comment: I can reach more than 100 retry because the retry is configured for every second, it's for test an API who process satellite image, so the response for image can take a while if the image is big.

Write some Java code can be usefull but it's seems to be to overkill...

I already test to fully disable `STDOUT` in `logback-test.xml` as you suggested.
Okay so I think this is the best approach, I have to extract the cucumber repport from the CI.

Thanks :) .

Comment: @RaphaelBahuau the `target/karate.log` file will exist - so you still have the complete logs

Comment: Yes I've already noticed the log file, but I like to watch log in real time on the CI, I find a compromise by only print error in `stdout` and full log in the file `karate.log` (but I prefer review full log with the html report).
I forgot to accept my bad !