# Is there a way to disable displaying request payload and respond body in console in Karate?

Tags: karate

My karate.log is around 13 GB when my performance test (karate-gatling) is executed. This is due to printing of request payload and response body in the console/log. I want to view all the information except request payload and response body in the log file.
Can anyone let me know how can I proceed ahead?

Comment: Just adjust the log config as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56937882/143475 and you can completely remove the `FILE` part also if you want. if you need more flexibility, please contribute code

Comment: Thomas, I have commented FILE part and STDOUT part in xml file. In console and karate.log file, it is not logging anything. In performance tests, few tests are getting failed. I want to know what exactly reason is. When I commented out FILE part, karate.log is more than 60 GB. So I could not open it. Therefore, please tell me if there is a way to disable only request payload and response body in log file.

Comment: try setting the log level to INFO or WARN as per the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate#logging - if that does not work, please contribute code or look for other options

Comment: I have set log level to ERROR. Now only errors are being logged. Thanks, Peter.