# How can I print the request and response logs written to Karate.log with logback-test.xml, one under the other?

Tags: karate

I am doing a performance test with Karate and I am examining the responses that receive errors in my karate.log file created after the test, but since the responses and requests are mixed in the log file, I cannot find the request of the relevant response, for example, there is a response that gets an error and I want to get its request and check it.

Can a change be made in logback-test.xml here to print the log? Or is it normal for the log structure to be like this because the users work consecutively during the performance test?

I tried to get the transactions with this dispatcher name in the log "GatlingSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5", but I did not get the result I wanted.

Tried level="ERROR"

This is my logback-test.xml

```
<configuration>

<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file>target/karate.log</file>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<logger name="com.intuit.karate" level="DEBUG"/>
<logger name="demo" level="DEBUG"/>
<logger name="mock" level="DEBUG"/>

<root level="warn">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
</root>
```

Comment: sorry you are on your own here - teams should ideally never have logs switched on in performance testing mode because it severely affects performance. refer: https://stackoverflow.com/q/69074401/143475

Comment: @PeterThomas I understand, since the team I work for made such a request, I thought there might be a solution. As you said, printing the logs affects the performance a lot, so I prefer not to print the logs, but they request the relevant request to debug the cause of the error. Thank you so much.