# Reducing log level to INFO for Karate Netty Server

Tags: netty, karate, mockserver-netty

I am running the Karate Netty Mock Server as forward proxy server in my QA environment. Our QA environment is prod-alike and gets a huge amount of traffic. I was wondering if there is a way to reduce the log levels to INFO rather than DEBUG ?

Also I was wondering if there is way to pass config properties file which can be utilized by Java classes used by our feature files, as this is running as proxy server. I have read some other documentation where it is mentioned that karate-config.js doesn't work with Netty Server.

Comment: I'm sorry, this question is rather vague and I will ignore the second part. for logging, refer: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#logging and https://stackoverflow.com/a/56937882/143475 - if you need more help, I personally feel you should help others replicate, and open-source contributions are always encouraged: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue